# Add description to table metadata

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata

What's the best way to add a table description to a table in the metadata? Also, what about for each specific table as well?  This is for an oracle Database.

When we use spy-schema to generate a schema I want to be able to show a description for each table and also a description of its columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never-mind, I found my own answer:

- **Create a comment on a table**

  comment on table x is 'This is table x';
- **Create a comment on a column:**

  comment on column t.x is 'This is column X of table T';

to view these comments:

- **View Column comments**

  select * from user_col_comments where table_name = 'x';
- **View Table comment**

  select * from user_tab_comments where table_name = 'x';

Hopefully this helps someone else..

Comment: Yes, this looks amazingly similar to Tom Kyte's Ask Tom entry, https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:233014204543.  If you used his example, perhaps you should give him credit.